# Angular 2+ jQuery dynamically add routerLink to html

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a json object, which I want to show on the page with highlighting, folding etc. [ngx-json-viewer](https://github.com/hivivo/ngx-json-viewer#readme) allows rendering json with formatting, folding etc. In this json, there are certain values which I want to convert to hyperlinks. I am trying to dynamically add routerLink to these values.

I am able to use jQuery modify the json after it is rendered and add anchors like so:

```
main.find('.segment-key').each(function() {
  const key = $(this).html();
  if(key == replacement.key) {
    main.find('.segment-value').each(function() {
      let value = $(this).html();
      if(!_.startsWith(value, '<a')) {
        value = _.replace(value, '"', '');
        $(this).wrapInner(`<a href="${replacement.anchor}` + value + '" />');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The anchors cause the page to refresh. I would like to replace the anchors with routerLink.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

PS: For anyone interested, I got this behaviour by adding a click event and handling the navigation in the controller:

```
main.find('.segment-key').each(function() {
  const key = $(this).html();
  if(key == replacement.key) {
    main.find('.segment-value').each(function() {
      let value = $(this).text();
      value = _.replace(value, new RegExp('\"','g'), '');
      if(!$(this).hasClass('hyperlink')) {
        $(this).addClass('hyperlink');
        $(this).on('click', function() {
          self.router.navigate([replacement.page, replacement.param + '/' + value]);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery to dynamise your view. Standart Angular component can handle that.

Moreover, I strongly recommand you to avoid using JQuery with Angular. Anything triggered by JQuery is out of Angular's sight. This said, you'll have to enter in a way more complexe implementation.

You'd better manipulate your DOM with tools provided by Angular itself.

Comment: Any pointers to those "standard Angular components" would help. I am happy to enter in a way more complex implementation if standard Angular components do not exist (I couldnt find one).

Comment: The main purpose of angular is to create your component. Then create one to handle your links. If you want more help you'll need to provide more information about your program (what's it's supposed to do for instance)

Comment: I have a json object, which I want to show on the page with highlighting, folding etc. ngx-json-viewer allows rendering json with formatting, folding etc. In this json, there are certain values which I want to convert to links (dynamically, since it is a dynamic json). I hope it makes sense?

Comment: I think, the easiest solution would be to add a click action and then do a router.navigate in controller.